# os.path.getmtime is more recent than now

Tags: python

I have a very simple code snippet

```
dirtime = os.path.getmtime(directory)
now = time.time()
```

If I print both values dirtime seems to be 3 seconds after now.  Any explanation for this?

Comment: What environment are you on?

Comment: can you show us your print and how you calculate the 3 seconds?

Comment: Is it on a network file server? Your clocks may be out of sync.